Get Error String for IcmpSendEcho Function ErrorCode
I am using this implementation of an icmp ping in delphi. Now i tried to get a human readable error message in case the device was not reachable so that i can print it in the error log.
Can you please explain to me how i can get the human readable error code that is defined here without having to do a switch case and manually writing the strings. I'm fine with using SysErrorMessage, GetIpErrorString or any other WinApi or basic delphi Function if there is one.
I already tried those two methods i found on the internet:

SysErrorMessage but that resulted in unrelated text.

GetIpErrorString function but im just not getting it to work correctly. My current trials just resulted either in an access violation or a seemingly random byte array.
Current external function definition and method call are like this:


function GetIpErrorString(
    const ErrorCode : ULong; 
    out Buffer : Pointer; 
    const Size : PDWORD
): DWORD; stdcall; external 'iphlpapi.dll';

var
  errorText         : string;
  bufferSize        : Integer;
  status            : ULong;
  ptr               : pointer;
begin

    // Here is the ping stuff. 
    // i already verified that this works as the numbers for the
    // responseCode are what i would from icmp send error

    status := GetLastError();
    bufferSize := 200;

    GetIpErrorString(
      status,
      ptr,
      @bufferSize
    );

    SetString(errorText, PChar(ptr), 5);
end


GetIpErrorString() expects you to allocate an output buffer and pass it via the Buffer/Size pair. It does not allocate a buffer for you. On successful return, the value pointed to by Size will have been updated to designate the length written to Buffer by the function.

@IInspectable thanks for the answer it pointed me in the right direction. After allocating the buffer i got an access violation again. I then looked up what out in delphi does and changed out Buffer : Pointer; to const Buffer : Pointer;. Now it is working correctly.

Thanks to IInspectable i got it working now. I misunderstood what 'out' does in delphi, thats where the access violations were from. So i changed the Function to
function GetIpErrorString(
  const ErrorCode : ULong; 
  const Buffer : Pointer; 
  const Size : PDWORD
): DWORD; stdcall; external 'iphlpapi.dll';

and initialized the string errorText to the length bufferSize before calling the method
SetLength(errorText, bufferSize);
GetIpErrorString(
  status,
  Pointer(errorText),
  @bufferSize
);

